# Resource-provided integer being garbled at runtime

Tags: java, android-resources

In my Android app, I've created the file app/src/main/res/values/integers.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="server_port">8080</integer>
</resources>
```

I then have

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    final MyServer server = new MyServer(R.integer.server_port);
}
```

However, when the app launches, a log statement reveals the value (i.e., `R.integer.server_port`) to be 2131296322.

Why is the value being garbled?  Is that not how integer resources are supposed to be implemented?

Comment: What exactly do you write to log - `R.integer.server_port` or `server.port`?

Comment: `R.integer.server_port`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.integer.server_port` gives the *resource ID* of the integer, not the integer itself.  In order to get the actual integer, you have to do `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.server_port)`.  However, this requires some modification to your original code as the resources won't have been set up by the time `MyApplication` is instantiated.  Instead, you can do

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    MyServer server;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        server = new MyServer(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.server_port));
    }
}
```

Of course, `server` won't be `final` anymore.  You can refactor to

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private MyServer server;

    public MyServer getServer() {
        return server;
    }

    ...
```